# Where to put handlebars template in a nodejs + emberjs application?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Ember in a Node + Express based project. I put client code under public/javascript and serve it using the `index.jade` file that we have by default in every `express` project. I need to use `handlebars` template for my client views but I can't figure out how to do this. Where should I put my template files and how the node server will compile and serve them ? Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [hbs](https://github.com/donpark/hbs)? Check the examples directory

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this library for the Handlebars templating with node.js + express.

https://github.com/donpark/hbs

Here are the steps to start using Handlebars in your node + express setup

Install the hbs npm module with

```
npm install hbs --save
```

Import the module and change the view engine to use hbs.

```
var hbs = require('hbs')
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

(Optional) To use partials, you ll need to register partials.

```
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
```

The files should be in the views folder with an extension of .hbs. You can change this if need be.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '<your_folder_name>'));
```

Check here more for partial naming conventions https://github.com/donpark/hbs